# WCF handling objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a class which is placed in a class library:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a repository class:

```
 public class Repository
{
    public List<UserProfile> GetUsers()
    {
        using (var context = new DBContext())
        {
            List<UserProfile> list = context.UserProfiles.ToList();
            return list;
        }

    }
 }
```

business logic class:

```
public class BusinessLogic
{
    public List<UserProfile> GetUserProfiles()
    {
        Repository repo = new Repository();
        List<UserProfile> list = repo.GetUsers().ToList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

and finaly WCF:

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<UserProfile> GetUserProfiles();
}


public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public List<UserProfile> GetUserProfiles()
    {
        BusinessLogic.BusinessLogic bl = new BusinessLogic.BusinessLogic();
        List<UserProfile> list = bl.GetUserProfiles().ToList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to get user profiles from wcf, it returns empty list.

However, if I skip wcf and get `List<UserProfile>` straight from businesslogic, it works perfectly fine.

I tried to debug. Results: when inside wcf it gets list from businesslogic, it's already empty. But as I said earlier, business logic works perfectly fine (returns necessary information).

There were similar posts but none of them did help me.

How can I make my WCF return a list filled with necessary information?

P.S. I do not want to add a copy of my class `UserProfile` into wcf with `[DataContract]` flag

Comment: Why are you calling `ToList()` on all levels? Your repository already returns `IList`, so it's safe to remove call to `ToList` in `BusinessLogic` and `Service1`.
Another thing to try, add reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization` dll in your library where `UserProfile` is declared and add `[DataContract]` attribute on top of it. See if that helps, although I would try to put a breakpoint inside WCF method and step into call to `bl.GetUserProfiles()` to see how come list returned is empty.

Comment: I know, at first I thought this problem was somehow associated with WCF handling lists so I wrote .ToList() just to make sure. Yes, it's safe to remove them, you are right

Answer (score 2):

Your object must either be serializable or decorated with that DataContract attribute.  Your return type from WCF must also be decorated with the DataContract attribute, and the member containing your List must be marked with the DataMember attribute.  This is required by WCF's DataContractSerializer in order to properly serialize the data and return it to the consumer.  Converting a class for transmission over the wire requires serialization.  There isn't a practical way to get around this with WCF.

Your list is empty because your UserProfile class cannot be serialized.

EDIT:

I just saw you are simply returning a list, which is already serializable, so if you just make your UserProfile class serializable or decorate it with the appropriate DataContract/DataMember classes, it will start working fine.

Comment: But I've read on other posts, that it's not required nowadays to use DataContract atribute. 
So if I made my object serializable, could I keep it outside wcf in class library and it should work fine?

Comment: @Tautvydas any link you can share that says nowadays using `DataContract` attribute is not required? I found [quite opposite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438669/how-do-you-return-a-user-defined-type-from-a-wcf-service).

Comment: You can use either the DataContract attribute (which is related to the DataContractSerializer) or the Serializable attribute, but the class must somehow be serializable.  WCF serializes data before transmission.

Keep in mind, the class does not have to be in your WCF class library.  You can mark any class in any library as a DataContract or serializable.  I do this all the time (putting business objects in separate libraries) and it works fine.

Comment: @Michael maybe I did not quite understand those posts

Comment: @DVK Now my class looks like this

    `[DataContract]
      public class UserProfile
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }`

I did clean rebuild. It still returns empty list

Comment: If you are sure that the data is there when WCF sends it, but it isn't coming across on the client, try wrapping the response in a DataContract that has your List as a member, marked with the DataMember attribute.

Comment: @DVK that's the problem. This line on wcf `List<UserProfile> list = bl.GetUserProfiles().ToList();` makes an empty list. However, if I write the same line not in wcf, it works. I'm sure only on that

Comment: I see.  Then the error is in the GetUserProfiles method then.  Code inside a WCF library works the same as code in any other library.  Serialization only comes into play when the data is actually sent over the wire to whatever is calling WCF.  Inside WCF, it is just normal, everyday C# code.

Comment: But how come then when I skip wcf and get list directly from businesslogic method `GetUserProfiles`, it returns my data, but when I try to get the same list from businesslogic in wcf, it fails? That's why I assume the problem is in WCF

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `List<UserProfile> list = bl.GetUserProfiles().ToList(); ` and executing that line returns no data, then WCF is not the problem, as the WCF framework has not done anything yet.  At that point it is just executing code the same as any class library.  I'd recommend debugging directly into `GetUserProfiles()` to find out why that method returns no data.  I could be something simple like a bad connection string.

Comment: Also, after making changes to any classes served by WCF, you must update the service references on the client app.  Otherwise it doesn't know about modified classes.